# jQuery .each(index, item) does not provide a jQuery object by default

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently doing some dom manipulation using jQuery.

I have multiple places in which I am looping through items, matching a particular selector. And do call some jQuery methods on them.

Let say we have something like this:

I am looping using:

```
myElement.find('.child-selector').each(function (index, item) {
        if (item.attr('some-attribute') == 'target-value') {
          // Do something
          // For instance item.detach()
        } else {
          item.hide();
        } 
});
```

As you most probably guessed already this will throw an error as .attr is undefined. Which is completely normal.

So in order to use the attr or any other jQuery method I need to do something like:

```
myElement.find('.child-selector').each(function (index, item) {
        item = $(item)
        if (item.attr('some-attribute') == 'target-value') {
          // Do something
        }
});
```

But I find this a bit annoying to have this boilerplate all around the source code. Do you know any better way to avoid adding `item = $(item)` as first statement all the time?

Comment: `$(item)` is the same as `$(this)`

Comment: @Jean-MarcZimmer I don't see how this affects the question.

Comment: Instead of using the `item` argument, then transforming it into `$(item)`, you can just use `$(this)` (Note that `this` is a JS object, `$(this)` is a JQuery object.)

Comment: @Jean-MarcZimmer both are the exact same thing.  just one uses `this` vs the passed in variable

Comment: true. But using `this` is better than a variable.

Comment: That is your opinion which reflects your own personal coding style, not an absolute.  Also if you use an arrow function for a callback, `this` is not bound, which would make your statement flawed.  Also `this` **is** a variable.

Comment: I guess I oversimplified the example. Sorry guys. This is already bound to actual object.

Comment: @Jean-MarcZimmer yes `item` an `this` are the same thing. I still fail to see why you believe that to be relevant - all that happens is you swap one variable with another but the exact same pattern of code remains - you'd still need to wrap the variable in a jQuery object. OP is asking for a way to not do that.

Comment: @vlaz You're right. But I think (It's my personnal opinion) that using `$(this)` or `$(item)` directly makes the code more readable, as it clearly shows we are using a JQuery object, and not a plain JS object. When I define a variable as a JQuery object I always make its name as `$variable`

Comment: @Jean-MarcZimmer but *this is not what the question is about* - it's not about how to name variables. Even if you were to do `$this = $(this)` or `$item = $(item)` you  *still* have the exact same problem that OP outlined. That's why I couldn't get why you kept suggesting something that doesn't in any way address the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could potentially make your own utility method.  You would just want to make sure that other programmers know it is a custom method and not a built in method of the api.

```js
jQuery.fn.customEachWithObject = function (callback) {
  if (callback instanceof Function) {
    this.each(function(index, element){
      callback(index, $(element));
    });
  }
};

$('div').customEachWithObject(function(index, $element){
  if (index == 0) $element.css('backgroundColor', 'red');
  if (index == 1) $element.css('backgroundColor', 'green');
  if (index == 2) $element.css('backgroundColor', 'blue');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid not, but you can write:

```
myElement.find('.child-selector').each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('some-attribute') === 'target-value') {
          // Do something
        }
});
```

Comment: This looks nice, but will not work if I do bind the this to a different object.. :(

Comment: That's true if you override the context, but you're not using arrow functions and you're not binding the anonymous function's context